# How to destroy OpenEBS cluster?

Tags: openebs

I have installed OpenEBS cluster with 0.5.4 version and playing with it. Now I want to delete the cluster and want to deploy latest OpenEBS 0.6.0 version so I can test latest features like snapshot,node selector etc. So how to destroy my existing OpenEBS cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Before deleting the OpenEBS please keep in mind to delete all PVC, PV, Deployments, SVC. Then delete the storage class. Once they are cleared you can remove OenEBS using any of the bellow methods.

1. If you have installed through operator yaml

   `kubectl delete -f openebs-operator-x.yaml`
2. If you have installed through Helm

   `helm install openebs-charts/openebs`
3. Else you can delete the namespace where OpenEBS has been installed. By default OpenEBS gets installed in the *openebs* namespace.

   `kubectl delete ns openebs`